# For loop with two arguments in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to implement this loop with Coffeescript

`for( var i = arr.length; i--; )`

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know any coffescript but aren't you supposed to have some kind of exit condition to that loop  ? And what is actually your problem ?

Comment: @Bartdude The exit condition is `i--`. When that evaluates to a falsy value (ie, 0) the loop will exit. This is completely fine. The problem is that that loop is a *JavaScript* loop, and he's trying to figure out how to write the equivalent CoffeeScript loop.

Comment: @Bartdude The question is straightforward if you've done any work with Coffeescript.

Comment: Well, I'll be a little less stupid when going to bed this evening. As I stated I don't know any coffeescript, but will have a look at it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in [arr.length-1..0] by -1
    # Something!
```

Comment: This is great. I'm going to try it out now.